# How to create ng-change dynamicly within ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have a div that is repeated which has a select (drop down menu) and it contains 3 option in it 'single', 'double', 'matrix' and on this selected values i have to show the following divs.
    Like if i select double value from the select list then it should show its relative div. and so on for others

Now the problem is here, when the ng-repeat is looped 4 times 
    and i select and change one of the dropdown list value then the other 3 divs also gets effected which should not happen.

```
<div ng-repeat="data in dataList">
        <select ng-change="getData()" ng-model="getSelectedItem"
            ng-options="i.value as i.text for i in formList">
        </select>   

        <div ng-show="showPanel=='single'">
            ...
        </div>
        <div ng-show="showPanel=='double'">
            ...
        </div>
        <div ng-show="showPanel=='matrix'">
            ...
        </div>
        ...

    </div>
```

my controller code

```
$scope.getSelectedItem = '';

$scope.getData = function(){
    if($scope.getSelectedItem == 'single'){
        $scope.showPanel='single'
    }else if($scope.getSelectedItem == 'double'){
        $scope.showPanel='double'
    }else if($scope.getSelectedItem == 'matrix'){
        $scope.showPanel='matrix'
    }
}
```

so, can i have "getData()" function dynamic like sperate for each ng-repeat
and how can i use that in controller. or is there another simple method
through which i can perform ng-change event and that will apply for that particular section only and not effect other divs.

Please help me out

Thanks.

Comment: please show your controller/directive code as well

Comment: you ng-model points to the same variable

Comment: what you `getData` event is going to please add a code of it.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you share your controller code as well. but I can predicts following:

1. formList is coming from parent scope (i.e dataList) NOT from ng-repeat child scope (i.e not from data)
2. getSelectedItem is also coming from parent scope as well
3. You are modifying model getSelectedItem inside the event "ng-change"

Above corrects?

Comment: So solution is either move getData and  getSelectedItem into child scope i.e. data  OR modify getSelectedItem using a directive in place of controller

Comment: can you pls post some example of it as, it would be great and helpful for me further

Comment: Do you really need ng-change="getData()"  for any other operation except showing respective div? If not , you can simply remove it and replace "showPanel" by getSelectedItem. For example: <div ng-show="showPanel=='single'"> will be <div ng-show="getSelectedItem=='single'">

Comment: No i need ng-change="getData()" as m performing some other stuff as well like calling a service and deleting the data.

Comment: You can do other stuff on-change but Does hiding DIVs depends only on select value Or other staff? Basically your problem is that you are using same scope for all rows for the variable 'showPanel'. It should be different for each row

Comment: Yes hiding DIVs depends only on select value

Answer (score 0):

Try ngSwitch directive: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch

```
<div ng-repeat="data in dataList">    
    <select ng-model="getSelectedItem" ng-options="i.value as i.text for i in formList"></select>
    <div ng-switch on="getSelectedItem">
        <div ng-switch-when="single"> //SINGLE-CONTENT </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="double"> //DOUBLE-CONTENT </div>
        <div ng-switch-when="matrix"> //MATRIX-CONTENT </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

If you want to do something within only one iterated object scope (data) you can pass it into the function as a parameter.

```
ng-change="getData(data)"
```

Then process it in the controller.

EDIT2:

You could also add property to the iterated object with the information of the selected item. You will be sure that selection is tied to the particular item from ng-repeat.

```
ng-model="data.selectedItem"
```

Comment: 1) on changing the select value i also want to perform some other stuff as well. 2)  ng-model="getSelectedItem" will get repeated with in ng-repeat will it be fine. means will it not effect other repeated divs